# ASP.Net compare validator on valid Date but on different culture value

Tags: asp.net

I want to validate date using `(dd/MM/yyyy)` format. I am using CompareValidator of asp.net but it does not validating valid date on this format. It is validating date on `(MM/dd/yyyy)` format. How to use compare validator with `(dd/MM/yyyy)` format

I am using CV as:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="chkStartIsDate" runat="server" 
    Display="Dynamic" Operator="DataTypeCheck"
    Type="Date" ControlToValidate="txtProjectStartDate" 
    ErrorMessage="Supply a valid start date" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting [CultureInvarientValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.cultureinvariantvalues.asp)?

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you set the Page culture to the dd/MM/yyyy culture, the validator will validate the input for you

Set the culture like this in your aspx.cs class:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    Page.Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag(LanguageShort).ToString();
    Page.UICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag(LanguageShort).ToString();
}
```